# Is message passing in small talk and ObjectiveC same as calling method with value types (structs) in argument?

Tags: objective-c, language-agnostic, language-design, smalltalk, message-passing

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing#Message_passing_versus_calling) the difference between message passing and calling a method is "In message passing, each of the arguments has to have sufficient available extra memory for copying the existing argument into a portion of the new message" while in the method call only the address of the arguments is passed.

How is message passing different than calling a regular method all arguments of which are structs or value type i.e. they all have to be pushed entirely in stack for the callee to be able to use them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once the actual function call is made, there is no difference. The difference between message passing and calling a method is in the linking. For languages like c and c++ the function calls are linked at compile time with the linker (except with virtual functions which requires some runtime support). With languages that use a messaging system like objective-c and smalltalk, you cannot guarantee what functions will be run until runtime. The runtime determines if an object actually implements the function represented in the message. If it doesn't implement it, the class will usually either forward the message onto another object, or throw an exception. However, if the class does implement it, the runtime determines the address of the actual function, and calls it in the exact same manner as c (pushing the arguments and the return address onto the stack).

Overall, a message is the same thing as calling a method directly, except the runtime finds the exact function to be called instead of it being linked at compile time.

Comment: This description sounds similar to Java's reflection API at the implementation level. Is it?

Comment: It has some similarities but it is not exactly the same. Objective-C has something called "Categories" which is just like Java's reflection. The way that Objective-C is implemented allows reflection (through categories) like Java but also allows run-time modification and forwarding of messages.

Answer (score 7):

The Objective-C calling ABI is generally (it would be possible to write your own ABI if you wanted) 100% pure C ABI;   parameters and return values are handled exactly as they would with a normal C call site.

The one key difference is that an Objective-C call site is always compiled as a variant of `objc_msgSend()` and the first two parameters are always the targeted object (`self`) and the selector to be invoked (`_cmd`).  This is what enables the dynamic dispatch -- the ability to override methods at runtime and the like -- that makes Objective-C considerably different than C++ (or similar).

For more than you could ever possibly need to know about `objc_msgSend()` (outside of the runtime and compiler team), I wrote a [4 part series giving a by-instruction tour of `objc_msgSend()`](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/).

Comment: Your blog posts explain it in a more detailed manner I would accept your answer too if it was possible.

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked to is talking about remote message passing, a la SOAP or CORBA. That really doesn't have a lot (if anything) to do with Objective-C message passing. (Yes, wikipedia's Objective-C article links to it - that link really shouldn't be there.)

The difference between sending a message and calling a method is that the former is highly dynamic. The mapping of a message name to the function that handles it is done at run time, whereas a method call is bound to a function at compile time.

This allows for a type of dynamic programming that one can't readily do in C++. For example, the Objective-C runtime will look for a -forwardInvocation:, and call it if an object doesn't directly respond to a specified message. This allows a class such as NSProxy, which can act as a "stand in" for any other class, without having to know all of the details of the class for which it's a proxy.

Another example is extending a class definition at run time, without needing to recompile or even restart one's application - all one needs to do is register the implementation function with the runtime.

Yet another example is supportive of language bridges. My own Cocoa/Perl bridge, for example, has only one implementation function that handles *any* message sent to a Perl object - it examines the message name and calculates, on the fly, what Perl function should be called in response.

Edit: Incidentally, once the function to handle a given message is resolved, the mechanics of calling that function - i.e. building the stack frame to pass the arguments - are precisely the same as they would be if the name-to-function binding were done at compile time. The notion that arguments are passed differently is just a red herring introduced by the off-topic wikipedia article.